# Write a csv file in Python : error with function writerows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Trying to save a list of lists into a csv file, I used the csv module. Here is my script :

```
import csv
a = [[1.2,'abc',3],[1.2,'werew',4],[1.4,'qew',2]]
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerows(a)
```

When I run this script, an error message appears :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "csv-ex.py", line 5, in <module>
writer.writerows(a)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Anyone knows what is missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You opened the file in binary mode, but the `csv.writer()` object sends strings.

Open the file in text mode by dropping the `b`. It is also recommended you set `newline=''`:

```
with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
```

See the [`csv` module footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the `csv` module does its own (universal) newline handling.

In Python 2, it was recommended to open the file in binary mode for the same reasons, but the I/O layer in Python 3 handles this much better with the `newline` option.