# Issue with using the zip function and writerows to create a CSV file

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python (3 weeks in) and am trying to create some code of scrape some data from a webpage.  I have been able to use xpath to create some lists of data.  So here I have a list of offices and a list of contacts.

In order to combine them, I used the zip function as you see below.  If I print the list(test) I can see that I get an expected result of a list with a bunch of tuples such as

```
[('\n101 Venture', '\nJeremy Baron'), ('\n1888 Management', '\nTrent May'), ('\n1919 Investment Counsel', "\nHarry O'Mealia"), ('\n2M Companies', '\nAmeeth Sankaran')]
```

Felt I was on the correct path based on this question: [Write a csv file in Python : error with function writerows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558219/write-a-csv-file-in-python-error-with-function-writerows)

However, the CSV File comes up empty whenever I open it.  Here is my code:

```
# combine lists from scraper
test = zip(office, contact_name)

#make CSV 
with open('some3.csv', 'wt') as csvfile:
    csv_out = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_out.writerows(test)
```

So not sure why I am not generating a CSV file with each tuple as a row and each element separated by a comma in the file.

Comment: It worked for me after I stripped the strings from the `'\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

```
test = zip(office, contact_name)


#make CSV 
with open('some6.csv', 'w+', newline="") as csvfile:
    csv_out = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in test:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```