# Python zip object is not written in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

This question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045398/issue-with-using-the-zip-function-and-writerows-to-create-a-csv-file#57045847), but I am interested in why this is a problem rather than a work-around to solve it:

I have some data with each category in one list, then zip it and then write it to a CSV file. This gives an empty CSV-file without any error or warning. Below, there is a sample code with different versions and I would like to understand why things work or not, what is the logic of it?

```py
import csv
import numpy as np

#original version
hist_data = [[0, 1, 'r'], [0, 0, 5], [np.array([11]),np.array([12]),np.array([13])], [0.22946621533609002, 0.21773800579739627, 0.1881331243203004], ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'], ['NaN','NaN', True], [1678615482.6110842, 1678615504.0591152, 1678615507.720184], [['some','list'],['more','data'], 'NaN'], [0, 1, None]]

zipped = zip(*hist_data)
converted_zipped = [[item for item in z] for z in list(zipped)]
list1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,7]]
tuple_list=[('a','b','c'),('d','e','f')]

filename='./zip_test.csv'
with open(filename,'w') as outputfile:
   writer=csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=';')
   # version a)
   writer.writerows(zipped) # -> does not work
   #version b)
   for row in zipped # -> as proposed in linked so question
      print('row:', row) #-> does not print anything
      writer.writerow(row) #-> does not work
   #version c)
   writer.writerows(list1) # -> works
   #version d)
   writer.writerows(tuple_list) # -> works
   #version e)
   writer.writerows(converted_zipped) # -> works
   # f)
   writer. writerow(zipped) # -> does not work
```

Comment: I use python 3.8.10. I have some older code where I used version a) and it worked (python 3.6). Is there a connection to the python version?

Comment: 1) What was the previous version of Python? 2) This `for row in zipped` should be `for row in zipped:`. 3) Three `zipped` is an iterator, once you do `converted_zipped` it is empty so `writer.writerows(zipped)` and `for row in zipped:` will not return anything 4) How is `reduced_zipped` being created? **ADD answers as update to question not in comments**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip()` returns an iterator and in your next line (`converted_zipped = ...`)  you **consume** this iterator. So when you next call `writer.writerows(zipped)` you will write nothing.

Consider this example:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

hist_data = [[0, 1, 'r'], [0, 0, 5], [np.array([11]),np.array([12]),np.array([13])], [0.22946621533609002, 0.21773800579739627, 0.1881331243203004], ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'], ['NaN','NaN', True], [1678615482.6110842, 1678615504.0591152, 1678615507.720184], [['some','list'],['more','data'], 'NaN'], [0, 1, None]]

zipped = zip(*hist_data)

filename='./zip_test.csv'
with open(filename,'w') as outputfile:
   writer=csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=';')
   writer.writerows(zipped)
```

Since you use the iterator `zipped` only once (in `writer.writerows`) the file with following content is created:

```
0;0;[11];0.22946621533609002;NaN;NaN;1678615482.6110842;['some', 'list'];0
1;0;[12];0.21773800579739627;NaN;NaN;1678615504.0591152;['more', 'data'];1
r;5;[13];0.1881331243203004;NaN;True;1678615507.720184;NaN;
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about the concept of iterators being consumed. How does one then usually use zip objects several times without converting it in this awkward manner as I did in converted_zipped?

Comment: @qcabepsilon You usually use list, [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) etc. But you can always create multiple `zip(*hist_data)` iterators.